# to use instance attributes in another python class

Tags: python

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, age, country, title, ph):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.country = country
        self.title = title
        self.ph = ph



class Programmer(User):
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address=address

    def do_something(self):
        print self.name
        print self.age
        print self.title
        print self.country + " " + self.ph


brian = User("brian", "28", "US", "Mr", "123556")

diana = Programmer("newark", brian)
diana.do_something()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/esurega/Desktop/NPI_TA/enm2enm/test/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    diana = Programmer("newark", brian)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: From your code, you only need to pass one argument when you initialize your instance `Programmer`, while you're passing two. The first argument `self` in `__init__()` just represents the instance itself.

Comment: You would write a `classmethod` that takes a `User` and an `address` and returns a `Programmer`.  You should also rewrite `Programmer.__init__` to take all of the arguments that `User.__init__` does, and pass them to the parent method with `super.__init__( name, age, country, title, ph)`

Comment: understood, but how to use attributes of instance "brian" in Programmer class.

Comment: You should just need to create a programmer instance since it is extending user, and either user **keyword *args or copy the argument signature from User in Programmer constructor to populate the properties Programmer is inheriting

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, Patrick and John....understood. But in that case, i need to give arguments 2 times? for example: `brian = User("brian", "28", "US", "Mr", "123556")
diana = Programmer("brian", "28", "US", "Mr", "123556","newark")
diana.do_something()`

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Comment: @sureshvarma if they are different users, then yes. By why are you using a `diana` variable to store a `Programmer` instance with the `name` "Brian"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the names brian,diana are just examples, i don't really have "user" or "names" in my code. Apologies, I know its a bad example and confusing. I have too many attributes (more than 20) from one class and wanted to use that instance in another class instead of creating them again. Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Programmer` class does not initialize any attributes of its parent class in the `__init__` method even though it inherits `User`.

You can either make `Programmer.__init__` initialize the parent class with a `User` object instead:

```
class Programmer(User):
    def __init__(self, address, user):
        super(Programmer, self).__init__(user.name, user.age, user.country, user.title, user.ph)
        self.address=address
```

or simply make a `user` attribute in the `Programmer` to reference the `User` it's based on, instead of making the `Programmer` class inherit `User`:

```
class Programmer:
    def __init__(self, address, user):
        self.user = user
        self.address = address

    def do_something(self):
        print self.user.name
        print self.user.age
        print self.user.title
        print self.user.country + " " + self.user.ph
```